# Addition Text to Post Titles (Custom Post Types) in RSS

Tags: posts, rss, feed

First, I have used this code to add my custom post types into my feed (below):

```
function myfeed_request($qv) {
    if (isset($qv['feed']))
        $qv['post_type'] = get_post_types();
    return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');
```

Later, I encountered [WPBeginner's Adding Additional Text to Post Titles in RSS](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-content-and-completely-manipulate-your-wordpress-rss-feeds/) and decided to modify the following code:

```
function wpbeginner_titlerss($content) {
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$gpost = get_post_meta($postid, 'guest_post', true);
$spost = get_post_meta($postid, 'sponsored_post', true);

if($gpost !== '') {
$content = 'Guest Post: '.$content;
}
elseif ($spost !== ''){
$content = 'Sponsored Post: '.$content;
}
else {
$content = $content;
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_title_rss', 'wpbeginner_titlerss');
```

Into this to suit the display of my custom post types in RSS:

```
function wpbeginner_titlerss($content) {
global $wp_query;
$post_type = $wp_query->post_type;

if( get_post_type() == 'essays' ) {
$content = 'Essay: '.$content;
}
elseif ( get_post_type() == 'gallery' ){
$content = 'Gallery: '.$content;
}
elseif ( get_post_type() == 'games' ){
$content = 'Game: '.$content;
}
else {
$content = $content;
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_title_rss', 'wpbeginner_titlerss');
```

This final code does not display my custom post types the way I want at all, any idea/help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're defining `$post_type`, why not just use it instead?

```
function wpbeginner_titlerss($content) {
    global $wp_query;
    $post_type = $wp_query->post_type;

    if( $post_type == 'essays' ) {
        $content = 'Essay: '.$content;
    }
    elseif ( $post_type == 'gallery' ){
        $content = 'Gallery: '.$content;
    }
    elseif ( $post_type == 'games' ){
        $content = 'Game: '.$content;
    }
    else {
        $content = $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_title_rss', 'wpbeginner_titlerss' );
```

(This assumes you have created custom post types, `essays`, `gallery`, and `games`.)